# select multi fields of data row into list c#

Tags: c#, list

i have filled data table from XML file and i would like to get data from this data table on condition like in case i need only 2 columns i will pass column name and then it will be generated into list values for only two columns and so on this is my trial

```
if (clist.Count == 2)
{
  string txt1 = ((TextBox)items_panel.Controls["txt" + 1.ToString()]).Text;
  string txt2 = ((TextBox)items_panel.Controls["txt" + 2.ToString()]).Text;

  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
    Xmlresults = dt.Select().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("loc")).ToList();
  }
}
else if (clist.Count == 1)
{
  string txt1 = ((TextBox)items_panel.Controls["txt" + 1.ToString()]).Text;

  foreach (DataTable dt in objDataSet.Tables)
  {
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
      Xmlresults = dt.Select().Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("loc")).ToList();
    }
  }
}
else if (clist.Count == 0)
{
  // List<string>[] list = new List<string>[4];

  foreach (DataTable dt in objDataSet.Tables)
  {
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
      Xmlresults = dt.Select().Select(dr => dr.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()).ToList();
    }
  }
}
```

`xmlresults` is global variable declared `public List<string[]> Xmlresults;`

It works fine for zero fields: it returns all columns in a list but for one I got error "can't convert type of list string to list string[]" and for two how I can get two columns on field name and each one in a list like that [0][1] [0] for column one and [1] for column two and so on

Comment: Why are you doing `"txt"+1.ToString()` in place of "txt1"? What is `Select()` supposed to mean? Where are you using `txt1`, `txt2`?

Comment: these are text box control which auto generated in run time and depend in these text box i am going to select columns

Comment: Can you answer my other questions?

Comment: thanks all i have added the values to data table and then i used them wherever i need .